# kill: invalid signal number or name: igterm

Tags: ibm-cloud, microservices, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty

I have an application deployed on cloud foundry, And when hit my application in browser getting the following error

> 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

And in the logs i found this error:

> [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR .app-management/scripts/start: 1: kill: invalid signal number or name: igterm

Any advise what that means ?

Comment: What command are you using to start your app? Is it related to `.app-management/scripts/start`? This script seems to be failing with the error you included.

Comment: My application on Cloud foundry, so  I am just pushing my app

Comment: This goes to what @josh is saying in his answer. `.app-management/scripts/start` isn't part of CF. It's something that's coming from your app & it's doing something weird. I don't know what's telling that script to run. If you're setting `cf push -c` or `command` in `manifest.yml`, that could be it. It could also be something triggered from some other script that is actually running. It's hard to say without knowing your app & what buildpack you're using to run your app.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same `.app-management/scripts/start: 1: kill: invalid signal number or name: igterm`

Answer (score 0):

`igterm` is not a valid signal number or name; that's true. HOWEVER, `sigterm` is ... i'm guessing there's just a typo there in the start script.

Comment: the script is auto-generated not created by me

Comment: That doesn’t really change my answer. Cloud Foundry can’t run buggy code; no platform can. My answer explains what your log message says which is what your question was. If you don’t own that code you should inform the author.